# Custom ListView with Switch and TextView in each item

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like a custom ListView containing a set of queues that a user can subscribe or unsubscribe to. Each item in my listview should consist of a RelativeLayout containing a TextView and a Switch. How do I go about populating this list ?

I have an array of JSON Objects where each JSON Object has a name and a string value(whether this user is subscribed to the queue or not. So :

- qInfo[i].optString("name") should set the Text of my TextView.
- qInfo[i].optString("value") should set the status of my Switch.

**queues_item :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/queuesLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/queues_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/queues_item_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textOn="Tilmeldt" 
        android:textOff="Frameldt"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a custom adapter and then inflate your view and return it with the correct data entered in.  There is a link below for an example, the main part is implementing the getView() method.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/